# Is it possible to prevent uitableviewcell to unload on device rotation?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Edit :
In short way :
How to prevent uitableview to call cellForRowAtIndexPath while rotation?

---

I have full screen mode with uitableview.
In that mode each cell is the size of the ipad screen.
The uitableview and the cell are using transform for horizontal scroll.
The uitableview is set pagingEnabled = YES

When I rotate the device, I layout all the frames/entities and call

beginUpdate
endUpdate

without call reloadData, this will only update the cell heights.

before the rotation starts, I save the indexpath of the current visible cell
, then ,in the willAnimate..rotate..method, I scroll to that indexpath, so the user will see the right cell.

the problem is on some situations, specially if the uitableview scroller is in the middle of the table, is that the uitableviewcell will unload, and uitableview will load diffrent uitableviewcell.

my question is :
I wonder if there is something to tell the uitableview to not "touch" the cells /reload/unload while rotating.

I know the  chances are low, but I wonder how others deal with situations when the current visible cell has complex interface + video is playing etc, and you dont want to stop the activity while rotating, with simple way to do that.

hope I'm clear here.

Comment: Cell's aren't unload. They are reused.

Comment: If I understood you right you don't want cellForRowAtIndexPath to change the data in the cell thats visible while changing the orientation?

Comment: @PetroKorienev
you are right. I meant preventing the visible cell, not be reused if rotating.

Comment: @Refael.S
mmmm one way to see it, is how to prevent uitableview to call cellForRowAtIndexPath while rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot prevent reusing. You can reuse cell's smart (for example, save cell's content before rotation / restore after rotation). For right positioning:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)io
{
    [self saveContentOfCells:[self.tableView indexPathsOfVisibleCells]];
    self.lastVisible = [[self.tableView indexPathsOfVisibleCells] lastObject];
}
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)io
{
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.lastVisible atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)ip
{
    // dequeue cell
    // try to restore content if any, clear restoration info
    // if no restoration info setup cell
    // return cell
}
```

Comment: I have all the content in some object,
the problem is the cell is active, meaning playing video, or making web requests.think about the cell as uiviewcontroller you dont want to destroy only because it's rotated.

after reading here, I'm thinking maybe to save the visible cell in property before rotation, then, if cellForIndexPath is call check:
if the indexpath is the visibleCell indexpath, return it.
if it's not, then create NEW cell and dont reuse cells.(only for rotation).after rotation ends, destroy all cell-for-rotation. but I'm not sure.

Comment: You didn't get the idea. Do you know when the objects are destroyed? When nothing holds strong references to them. So, when you save references to all critical content it's not get deallocated. You can save: MPMoviePlayer embedded into cell, the whole cell, URLConnection object etc. By save i mean, yes, storing them to `strong` properties.

Comment: your cell is not being destroyed its just being reused and set new data or same data again! try the answer I wrote to you with the isRotating BOOL property and tell me how it went

Comment: You also didn't get. What if the cell has video playing?

Comment: @PetroKorienev

you mean save the MPMoviePlayer to the entity that represents the cell content, at least before rotation, and  if cellForIndex called again,
when filling the cell with content, if there is mpmovieplayer object, show it in the cell ? somthing like this ?

Comment: Something like this, yeah. Say, cell holds instance of MPMoviePlayerController, you reuse them as usual but it you has MPMoviePlayerController stored in your VC, you don't create it for cell, instead use stored.

Comment: Also, some probable usability suggestion - you may not want the two videos play at the time (which seems to have sense), so the task becomes easier - you create moviePlayer for each cell in `cellForRow` and store moviePlayer only when you started playing video. Thereafter, in cellForRow when there's stored player you just assign it to appropriate cell. On player stop you just set stored player to nil which `frees` the reference to it and let's tableView do it's logic because player is now tied only to cell. This way you'll have to just scroll to necessary row after rotation

Comment: yep.
your answer, is the kind of answers that after someone is explaining too you, you wonder what was I thinking..and why I didnt see this myself. thanks man. and thanks for insisting to explain till get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a BOOL property to your viewController called isRotating and set isRotating to YES While rotating and at the end of the rotation set isRotating back to NO.
Use the isRotating in CellForRowAtIndexPath where you set all the data to the reused cell and put all these lines of code into an if.

Example for only a cell with a textLable text being changed:

```
if (!isRotating)
{
    cell.textLable.text = @"newData";
}
```

That will maybe work for you.